# Linking external libraries to ROS

Tags: ros, external-libraries

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I know this is something every c++ programmer has to know, but i'm java programmer and just started learning C++ and ROS.
If I have compiling flags like the following to compile a C++ program (not in ROS), how do I integrate this to a ROS program and modify my manifest or CMakeFiles?

`-l Festival -I/usr/include/festival  -I/usr/lib/speech_tools/include -leststring -lestools -lestbase`

EDIT: and are there any other settings that I have to do? like, setting dependencies for example (if that even makes sense)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28491/linking-external-libraries-to-ros/) by [Haikal Pribadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1779/haikal-pribadi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2012-02-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure if it is the best way I did this with the following in CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -I/usr/include/festival -I/usr/lib/speech_tools/include")
```

For linking target libraries

```
target_link_libraries(example rt
python2.6
other_libraries)
```

---

Originally posted by [ravenII](https://answers.ros.org/users/1831/ravenii/) with karma: 63 on 2012-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Haikal Pribadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1779/haikal-pribadi/) on 2012-02-25**:
I see you put in the -I (includes) flags, but where do we put the -L (libraries) ?? I don't understand your second section of code. Could you please, explain? thanks @ravenll, really..

**Comment by [ravenII](https://answers.ros.org/users/1831/ravenii/) on 2012-02-25**:
I think this page explains the procedure.
http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbuild/CMakeLists/Examples#Linking_against_an_external_library

**Comment by [Haikal Pribadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1779/haikal-pribadi/) on 2012-02-25**:
Uh, I did not see this link before. This keeps on happening to me. Where do they put all these intermediate tutorial links? or do you have to know the specific link to the secret page :) ? Thanks btw, ravenll..

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I add the same problem and I solved like this:

```
FIND_LIBRARY(EXT_LIBRARY extName library_full_path)

target_link_libraries(
  my_node
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${EXT_LIBRARY }
)
```

In my case I needed to add the library for a DepthSense camera:

```
FIND_LIBRARY(DEPTHSENSE_LIBRARY DepthSense /opt/softkinetic/DepthSenseSDK/lib/)

target_link_libraries(
  depthsense_camera_node
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${DEPTHSENSE_LIBRARY}
)
```

---

Originally posted by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) with karma: 541 on 2015-02-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-24**:
(a bit off topic) Not sure about its current status, but you might be interested in the [softkinetic](http://wiki.ros.org/softkinetic) package.